# Facebook App AccessToken on Client Side

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token, fbjs

Could Facebook page Accesstoken and Signed Request be exposed in client side aka javascript. ? is it a good option to store in db or in memory on server?

```
FB.login(function (response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
       FB.api('/me/permissions', function (perms_response) {
                                    call to server with this response.. 
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
                            }
                        }, { scope: 'manage_pages' }                    
);
```

Question is the response.authResponse.accessToken, response.authResponse.userID, response.authResponse.signedRequest are visible at the client or this needs to done in server side as well

Comment: Of course __not__. How is that not totally obvious to you in the first place?

Comment: i was referring to page access token from the response object. i have edited the question now. Let me know if you think my code is not supposed to be doing like this

Comment: The current user, that you get the page access token from, is able to manage the page anyway – so no big problem if they see the page access token. You should of course not expose it client-side to _other_ users, if that’s what you’re asking.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, what's the difference?

Its just that these shouldn't be requested from the client-side since client-side is exposed.

The app access token is just like a password to your app, if it gets leaked to someone, he can edit/destroy/do anything with your app!

So what you are trying to do is **NOT** recommended.

To get the **App Access Token**-

1. You can get it directly from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
2. You can make a call here to get that-

   ```
   GET /oauth/access_token?
       client_id={app-id}
       &client_secret={app-secret}
       &grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

Comment: I mean the page access token